# delay an alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

is it posible ??
I have an activity and an alertdialog on it.
but i need the activity run first and then 2 seconds later appears the alertdialog.
i have no idea how. regards

pd: iam not an english speaker

```
public class Pantalladeinicio extends Activity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000; 

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.index);


  if(checkInternetConnection()==true) {

  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   public void run() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Pantalladeinicio.this,
      NetworkingActivity.class);
    mainIntent.putExtra("MAIN", true);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
   }
  }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH); 

  } 

  else
  {
         AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");  
            dialogo1.setMessage("Debe activar la Conexion a Internet");            
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);  
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 


                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {  

                    aceptar();  
                }  
            }); 
            dialogo1.show();
      Log.v("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");


  }






 }


 public void aceptar() {
       // Toast t=Toast.makeText(this,"Bienvenido a probar el programa.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

     super.onDestroy();
      finish();

    }



 private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // test for connection
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            //Log.v("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");

            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you posted? (Don't call `super.onDestroy()` in `aceptar()` only use `finish()`.)

Comment: @Sam: he want 2 second delay before showing AlertDialog

Comment: @imrankhan Yes, I see a Handler with `postDelayed()` set to start a new app after two seconds. Why doesn't funkeeiads but an AlertDialog in there?

Comment: @Sam : he is starting `NetworkingActivity` using handler but i don't known why he required 2 second delay in else part for showing Alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as using `Thread` and `runOnUiThread`

```
  //Your Code here...
    else
      {
    myThread();
      }
    }
    public void myThread(){
        Thread th=new Thread(){

         @Override
         public void run(){
          try
          {

           Thread.sleep(2000);
           Pantalladeinicio.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Pantalladeinicio.this);  
                dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");  
                dialogo1.setMessage("Debe activar la Conexion a Internet");            
                dialogo1.setCancelable(false);  
                dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {  

                        aceptar();  
                    }  
                }); 
                dialogo1.show();
          Log.v("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");
               }
           });

          }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
       }
    }
        };
        th.start();
       }
```

Comment: That´s the answer..
Thanks for your help..
i´d invite you a beer..
regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question, but looking at the accepted answer I suggest changing the order of your existing code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(checkInternetConnection()) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Pantalladeinicio.this, NetworkingActivity.class);
            mainIntent.putExtra("MAIN", true);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        } 
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");  
            dialogo1.setMessage("Debe activar la Conexion a Internet");            
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);  
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {  
                    aceptar();  
                }  
            }); 
            dialogo1.show();
            Log.v("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");
        }
    }
}, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Thnks for your optimization, ill test it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to wait for 2 seconds after you get into the else block. 
You could do this by calling `Thread.sleep(2000);` before you call `dialogo1.show();`. However, this will make your program appear to "freeze". In order to avoid this you can create a seperate thread that sleeps and then displays the dialog.

Comment: i did that !! but freezed before to start the activity.
thanks

Comment: It is probably sleeping before the activity has a change to render. Try creating a separate Thread as I suggested. I would suggest taking a look at the Concurrency tutorial on the Oracle website, if you have time, to learn about Threads and how to use them properly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html Otherwise, take a look at imrankhan's example if you want a quick fix that might work for you.