# Android : Add delay to Alert Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, delay, alert

I am in a situation where i need an alert dialog to pop up after some seconds. I tried Handler with postDelayed(), it didn't work.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new
Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MyActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("My title...    ");
                builder.    setMessage("my msg..");
                builder.     setPositiveButton("OK",
                         new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int     which) {
                            Log.    e("info", "OK");
                            }
                        });

                builder.show();
        }
    });
        }
}, 33000);
```

Comment: you have to wait 33 seconds before now if it does work or no

Comment: I did, the alert dialog didn't pop up even after 40 seconds.

Comment: You could try Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 8):

You have to add this piece of code below builder.show(); It works for me.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }   
}, 1500);  // 1500 seconds
```

Edit:

I use this in a different way that I could see in your case. Here you can see my complete code. In my case I only want that apears a "simulate" Progress Dialog, and after some time it disappears.

```
protected void ActiveProgressDialog() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", getResources().getString(R.string.carregantInfo), true);
    dialog.show();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }   
    }, 1500);  // 1500 milliseconds
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry! i don't get you, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you before. I understand the opposite as you want. I'll try to find a solution. If i get something I'll post it! Sorry

Comment: I found that for you. Hope it helps!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652130/delay-an-alertdialog

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question by I think the problem might be that you aren't running from the main (UI) thread.

Make sure your handler is associated with the main thread with

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(...);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
private Thread mMainThread;

mMainThread = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(33);
                                try{

       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MyActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("My title...    ");
            builder.    setMessage("my msg..");
            builder.     setPositiveButton("OK",
                     new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int     which) {
                        Log.    e("info", "OK");
                        }
                    });

            builder.show();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }
            }};
```

Hope it helps